# Add google tink java lib in bazel

Tags: java, bazel, tink

I'm working on a java project where bazel is being used. I'm looking to add tink java lib in bazel but looks like `com_github_google_tink` is not a valid package name.

````
java_library(
    name = "testlib",
    srcs = glob(["*.java"]),
    deps = [
        "@com_github_google_tink",
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)```
I already referred this article https://developers.google.com/tink/install-tink but it only talks about adding java deps in maven. Can someone help ?
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using rules_jvm_external to get the tink dependency?

https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external

If not, you might try adding this or similar to your `WORKSPACE` file:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_TAG = "4.2"
RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_SHA = "cd1a77b7b02e8e008439ca76fd34f5b07aecb8c752961f9640dea15e9e5ba1ca"

http_archive(
    name = "rules_jvm_external",
    strip_prefix = "rules_jvm_external-%s" % RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_TAG,
    sha256 = RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_SHA,
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external/archive/%s.zip" % RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_TAG,
)
load("@rules_jvm_external//:repositories.bzl", "rules_jvm_external_deps")
rules_jvm_external_deps()
load("@rules_jvm_external//:setup.bzl", "rules_jvm_external_setup")
rules_jvm_external_setup()
load("@rules_jvm_external//:defs.bzl", "maven_install")

maven_install(
    artifacts = [
        "com.google.crypto.tink:tink:1.6.1",
    ],
    repositories = [
        "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2",
    ],
)
```

Then you can use the tink dependency from maven in your `BUILD` / `BUILD.bazel` file like this:

```
java_library(
    name = "testlib",
    srcs = glob(["*.java"]),
    deps = [
        "@maven//:com_google_crypto_tink_tink",
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```